# argumentException was unhandled error when converting byte of array to image

Tags: c#, .net, image

I have  done this one for converting the byte of array in one of the columns in gridview  to system.drawing.image  got an error        at this line

```
Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);        

              argumentexception was unhandled 
              Parameter is not valid.
```

and the code is like this

```
private byte[] objtoarray(object obj)
{         
    if (obj == null)
        return null;

    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bf.Serialize(ms, obj);

    return ms.ToArray();

}

public Image bytearraytoimage(byte[] bytearray)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytearray,0,bytearray.Length);

    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;

}

private void productGridview_Cellclick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] bits = null;
    Image img = null;

    if (e.ColumnIndex != productgridview.Columns["productimage"].Index) return;

    if (productgridview.SelectedCells.Count == 0) return;

    object selectedValue = productgridview.SelectedCells[0].Value;
    bits= objtoarray(selectedValue);
    img = bytearraytoimage(bits);

    if (img is Image)
    {
        // Forms are IDisposable, so use them embedded in a using statement.
        using (ProductDescriptionForm pf = new ProductDescriptionForm())
        {
            pf.picture = (Image)selectedValue;
            pf.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx) state that ArgumentException can be raise for :

```
The stream does not have a valid image format
-or-
stream is null.
```

So since `objtoarray` can return null, is `productgridview.SelectedCells[0].Value` null, or of an invalid value?

```
    object selectedValue = productgridview.SelectedCells[0].Value;
    bits= objtoarray(selectedValue);
```

Comment: Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);  i have seen the value for selectedValue is like this "byte[40678]"

Comment: i got the value at this statement like this   object selectedValue = productgridview.SelectedCells[0].Value; after this statement the seleceted value is like this byte[44899].... am i doing any thing wrong ....

Comment: thanq peter the data coming from grid view is also byte of arrays so no need to convert again into byte of arrays ....i made a mistake ..now its working fine.....